# Moving layer in Cartodb

Tags: carto, animation, torque

Take a look at [this map](http://cartodb.s3.amazonaws.com/static_vizz/sunrise.html?title=true&description=true&search=false&shareable=true&cartodb_logo=true&layer_selector=false&legends=false&scrollwheel=true&sublayer_options=1%7C1&sql=&zoom=2&center_lat=22.917922936146045&center_lon=51.328125#) entitled Sunrise around the world:

They have animated where the sun is shining around the world as a moving layer in their torque animation. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That map uses the Leaflet extension [L.terminator](https://github.com/joergdietrich/Leaflet.Terminator). This means that you need to build a map using the Leaflet and CartoDB.js library. Learning resources on CartoDB.js are in CartoDB's [Map Academy](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/03-cartodbjs-ground-up.html). You specifically want to use the `createLayer` method for creating your map as it easily works with the Leaflet library's layers.